# Run server's script from client's script

Tags: python, sqlite, server

I want to connect a Device (**raspberry pi**) to a server **using a network** and run a script on the server that will return information to the device.
The requirements are the following:

- The device uses a python script that I am supposed to implement.
- The server script needs to access the server’s database

  My questions are the followings:
- What is the **most suitable language** to use for the server’s script?
- How to I run a script on a server from another device using python?
- How do I return information from the server’s script to the client script?

Comment: It would be usefull if you say how will you connect the device with the server (usb, network, ssh...), and wich type of device it is.

Comment: There is no such most suitable language. Any suggestion is opinion based. You have various options, such as PHP, node, Python, Ruby... just name a few. It depends on your web server and what framework or CMS you are going to use.

Comment: For your last question, I think popular way can be XML or JSON.